# Passing an 2d array to a function

Tags: c++

I have the following in the main function

```
    void checkGrid(int rows, int cols, int **src){
        cout<<"Testing";
        int neighbors;

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; i < cols; j++){
                neighbors = getNeighborsCount(rows, cols, i , j, src);

            }
        }

    }
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc != 3) {
    cerr << "Invalid command line - usage: <input file> <number of threads>" << endl;
    exit(-1);
  }

  // Extract parameters
  ifstream ifile(argv[1]);
  int num_threads = atoi(argv[2]);

  // Set the number of threads
  task_scheduler_init init(num_threads);

  // Get the size of the problem - on the first line of the input file.
  int size;
  ifile >> size;

  // TODO: Create and initialize data structures
    int rows = size;
    int cols = size;
    int **grid_A = new int*[rows];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        grid_A[i] = new int[cols];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            ifile >> grid_A[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            cout << grid_A[i][j];
        }
    }


  // Start the timer
  tick_count start = tick_count::now();

  // TODO: Execute the parallel algorithm
    cout<<"Testing";
    checkGrid(rows, cols, grid_A);

  // Stop the timer
  tick_count end = tick_count::now();
  double run_time = (end-start).seconds();
  cout << "Time: " << (end-start).seconds() << endl;


  // TODO: Print the output to a file
//  ofstream outfile("output.txt");
//
//
//  outfile.close();
//
//  // Append the peformance results to the results file.
//  ofstream ofile("life.csv", ios::app);
//  ofile << size << "," << num_threads << "," << run_time << endl;
//  ofile.close();

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        delete[] grid_A[i];
    }
    delete []grid_A;

  return 0;
}
```

I am able to compile the program, but when i run the build file it doesn't print out the "Testing" statement. Could someone point out if this because of the way the 2d array is being passed in or is it something else.

**EDIT:** Posting entire segment of code as per requested, also i am new to C++ and just followed some examples on how to pass 2d arrays as parameters to a function

Comment: You don't pass an array (which can only be done by reference anyway) but a pointer to an int pointer, which happens to point to the beginning of a dynamically allocated array. And your code does not compile. Post compilable code please.

Comment: @ChristianHackl so i am using the following command to compile g++ life.cpp -o life -ltbb -std=c++11 and it didn't throw any errors. Hence i thought it compiled fine, but i might be wrong

Comment: Does it print `"Time : "`? This is the right time to use a debugger.

Comment: it doesn't print anything until comment out checkGrid()

Comment: `i < cols;` is the wrong condition in the inner loop in `checkGrid`. `i` is not modified in that loop, so it will spin until you dereference-fault (which may be awhile, or even never if `getNeighborsCount()`, which we can't see, is doing any sort of range checking).

Comment: @WhozCraig you are right, self smack in the face

Comment: Doesn't it output values of the grid? What is `size` value? Have you verified your input file contains enough data to fill `size*size` array? Have you checked the whole structure is allocated properly?

Comment: @CiaPan yes it allocates the data properly from the file

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Probably because you don't flush your `stdout`. Try `cout<<"Testing" << flush;`.</strike>

The reason that the rest doesn't even print is because of your loop in your `checkGrids` function:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; i < cols; j++){
        neighbors = getNeighborsCount(rows, cols, i , j, src);

    }
}
```

`for(int j = 0; i < cols; j++)` should be

```
for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
```

Currently that loop is just a deadlock.

Also, please don't use pointers like that, you're bound to get into trouble. There's a reason C++ has `std::vector`. Or for compile-time known lengths and C++11 `std::array`. That'll also save you the hassle of having to pass the lengths to `checkGrid`.

Comment: Program termination should trigger a flush automatically.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Right.